# Natural deduction, Proof $\vdash$ $P\Rightarrow(Q\Rightarrow P)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

So I have a question regarding natural deduction, are we
allowed to "copy" our previous assumption inside a new assumption.
I will use an example to illustrate.

$\vdash$ $P\Rightarrow(Q\Rightarrow P)$

So here are my steps.

1.) $P$             Assumption

2.)$Q$             Assumption

3.)$P$             Copy (1)

4.)$Q \Rightarrow P$   Implication Introduction

5.)$P \Rightarrow (Q \Rightarrow P)$ Implication Introduction

Is my proof correct, or is there something missing.

Comment: You don't have to "copy" the first assumption of $P$ — it remains an assumption! Otherwise, when would it end? You copy $P$ following the assumption of $Q$, but now it seems you'd have to copy $Q$...

Comment: In 4. and 5. you're not "introducing" anything, you're discharging assumptions (2. and 1. respectively).

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to tell me. So did I do anything wrong here ? Or its correct but with some unnecessary steps. If I make a mistake, could you kindly point it out for me. Thanks for replying

Comment: @BrianO The proof rule that says "if $P \vdash Q$ then $\vdash P \Rightarrow Q$" is usually called "implication introduction".

Comment: @BrianO: The rule is indeed implication introduction in some presentations of natural deduction, especially Fitch-style.

Comment: @BrianO: See my answer, where the implication symbol is introduced when the assumption structure is collapsed, and in minimal versions of natural deduction it is the only way to obtain the implication symbol in an assertion. The structure corresponds to the "$\vdash$" in Derek's comment.

Comment: Well then you never discharge the assumptions $P$ or $Q$, do you. We don't want to prove $P, Q\vdash P\to (Q\to P)$. Probably your point should be that it's not necessary to introduce $Q$ as an assumption, and just use "implication introduction" instead.

Comment: @BrianO: You've to use the `@<username>` to notify the user of a message. Anyway I'm not sure you understood what I said. In some systems, there is absolutely **no way** to obtain the implication symbol in an assertion **unless** you first create the assumption of the condition and prove under that assumption the conclusion, and only then can you use implication introduction. No other deductive rule can generate the implication symbol, hence the implication introduction rule **is necessary**.

Comment: @BrianO Yes you are allowed to copy or reiterate previous assumptions and or premises as long as you are in the appropriate scope.I don't think the OP meant copying assumptions is necessary, but is allowed. Also I think he meant that Q is an "inner" indented assumption, but he didn't properly indent.

Answer (score 3):

Just to make it clear why your solution is correct, here it is in Fitch-style:
$\def\imp{\Rightarrow}$

**Solution**

If $P$: [(1)]

If $Q$:

$P$. [(2); copy from (1)]

$Q \imp P$. [(3); implication introduction from (2)]

$P \imp ( Q \imp P )$. [implication introduction from (3)]

**Notes**

Intuitively it is obviously correct because whatever you can assert **outside** of any assumption is **still true inside** the assumption. That allows you to copy the outer assumption under the inner assumption as you did. The rest is just implication introduction as you did, which is nothing more than collapsing the assumption structure into a single line.

Comment: @user2875613: I should add that your solution is technically incorrect because you did not clearly specify the assumptions that are active for each line, unlike the Fitch-style solution I gave where the active assumptions are clearly shown using the indentation.

Comment: @user2875613: Do you understand my answer? If it is helpful, you can upvote it, and if you are satisfied with it you can accept it. If not, feel free to ask on any particular point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your proof is correct (modulo $P$ is added using a different rule than $Q$).

In natural deduction you have [structural rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_rule) called contraction, weakening, and exchange.
$$
\frac{S,P,P,T \vdash Q}{S,P,T \vdash Q}\ \text{contraction} \quad
\frac{S,T \vdash Q}{S, P, T \vdash Q}\ \text{weakening} \quad 
\frac{S,P,Q,T \vdash R}{S,Q,P,T \vdash R}\ \text{exchange}
$$

Usually, these rules are used silently by saying that the collection of assumptions forms a set.  You can imagine not having these as structural rules which leads to [substructural logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substructural_logic), the most notable of which is [linear logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_logic) which drops contraction and weakening.

We can now describe your proof (with the minor correction): $P$ is introduced via $P \vdash P$, then $Q$ is added to the assumptions via weakening ($P,Q \vdash P$), then you use contraction to duplicate $P$ ($P,P,Q \vdash P$) and exchange to bring it to the front of the context($P,Q,P\vdash P$), then two uses of implication introduction.

Comment: I believe the rules you describe are actually for sequent calculus, which Gentzen proved is bi-interpretable with natural deduction, though the two are quite different on the surface.

Comment: @user21820 While I am using sequent notation, the rules are (derivable) rules of natural deduction.

Comment: Yup that's what I said; "bi-interpretable".